# PHP, найти подстроку без учета пробелов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть строка (она может меняться), в ней нужно найти подстроку, например XYZ, вопрос заключаетсяв том что XYZ может меняться, в том плане что между буквами могут быть пробелы (один или несколько).

Как мне сделать проверку что в строке есть такая подстрока?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$str = 'XY  Z';

$patt = '~X\s*Y\s*Z~';
preg_match($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: есть строка (она может меняться)

Comment: @Ипатьев ну это понятно из первого поста .

Comment: не видно, чтобы было понятно

Comment: @Ипатьев ну вот в такой строке `ertert XY  Z ertert` будет найдена `XY  Z`

Comment: а в другой строке?

Comment: @Ипатьев например в какой? В такой --> `er tert XYZ erte rt` тоже всё окей. В чём дело?

Comment: Прошу прощения. похоже это я неправильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

А вы в строке сначала удалите все пробелы, а потом уже ищите подстроку.
Что-то вроде:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

а потом

```
$pos = strpos($string, 'XYZ');
```